# Subtracting Matrices in VBA?

Tags: vba

I am hoping that someone can help me with this question. I am quite new in VBA so my question might be silly. I do apologize in advance...:):

I have written the following fucntion that serves to subtract to matrices from each other:

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit

Function MatrixSubtract(matrix1 As Variant, matrix2 As Variant)

Dim row1 As Integer
Dim row2 As Integer
Dim col1 As Integer
Dim col2 As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim MatrixSubtract As Variant

row1 = UBound(matrix1, 1)
col1 = UBound(matrix1, 2)
row2 = UBound(matrix2, 1)
col2 = UBound(matrix2, 2)

If (row1 <> row2) Or (col1 <> col2) Then
    MsgBox ("Dimension mismatch. Subtraction can't be performed")
Exit Function
End If

ReDim diff(1 To row1, 1 To col1)

For m = 1 To row1
     For n = 1 To col1
         diff(m, n) = matrix1(m, n) - matrix2(m, n)
     Next n
Next m

MatrixSubtract = diff

End Function
```

When using the function in excel (subtracing a 1 by 2 matrix containing ones in all entries from a 1 by 2 matrix containing zero in all entries) I get a 1 by 2 matrix with #VALUE! in each cell.

However, if I write the same code a sub (see below) and give the same matrices as input as above, the code works? I suspect it has something to do with my syntax in the function? Thank you.

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit

Sub MatrixSubtract()

Dim matrix1(1, 2) As Variant
Dim matrix2(1, 2) As Variant

matrix1(1, 1) = 0
matrix1(1, 2) = 0
matrix2(1, 1) = 1
matrix2(1, 2) = 1

Dim row1 As Integer
Dim row2 As Integer
Dim col1 As Integer
Dim col2 As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim MatrixSubtract As Variant

row1 = UBound(matrix1, 1)
col1 = UBound(matrix1, 2)
row2 = UBound(matrix2, 1)
col2 = UBound(matrix2, 2)

ReDim diff(1 To row1, 1 To col1)

If (row1 <> row2) Or (col1 <> col2) Then
    MsgBox ("Dimension mismatch. Subtraction can't be performed")
    Exit Sub
End If

For m = 1 To row1
    For n = 1 To col1
        diff(m, n) = matrix1(m, n) - matrix2(m, n)
    Next n
Next m

MatrixSubtract = diff

End Sub
```

Comment: In the worksheet select the appropriate cells enter the function and press `[Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter]` for a cell array function. Also make sure the function returns a `Function MatrixSubtract(...) As Variant()`.

Comment: By the way Excel will do the subtraction on an array of cells for you without any `VBA` code. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-HA010342564.aspx

Answer (score -1):

No need for VBA code here. Excel has a built-in matrix manipulation mechanism. For addition and subtraction use regular function syntax into ranges of cells, and enter them as an array formula.

[image: Example 1]

Use also `TRANSPOSE()`, `MMULT()`, `MINVERSE()` and other built in functions for more complex operations.

If you want to write a function to return an array see the following example:

```
Public Function IdentityMatrix(ByVal N As Integer) As Variant()

    Dim vals() As Variant
    ReDim vals(1 To N, 1 To N)
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    For i = 1 To N
        For j = 1 To N
            If i = j Then
                vals(i, j) = 1#
            Else
                vals(i, j) = 0#
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    IdentityMatrix = vals
End Function
```

To be used as:

[image: Example 2]

With result:

[image: Example 3]

Comment: @ ja72 Thank you your answer. Unfortunately, I do press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] so this is not the problem. I am aware that excel can subtract and add array of cells, but this does not solve my problem. I need excel to subtract and add lots of matrices with various dimensions. So I need to automate it with VBA I suppose.

Comment: You _have_ to select the correct number of rows and columns and if those change you cannot do it with `Function As Variant()`. You may need to resort to macros `Sub()` and pull values with `vals = Range("A1").Resize(10,3).Value`.

Comment: Okay, I see. I was not aware of that - thanks! :) I have now created a function that takes rows and coulms as input and works.